# Graylog2 not showing any messages in specific stream

Tags: regex, symfony, monolog, graylog2

In our Symfony2 application we query an external API for a certain service we provide. This API (let's call it `Acme API`) sometimes throws error messages that we forward to Graylog2 via Monolog and Gelf to keep track of outages. Every error is logged on `error` level with `$logger->err()`.

The messages are shown in the normal message pool, but the custom stream that collects these API error messages isn't showing any message at all.

So my main question is: Why is Graylog refusing to show messages in the stream and what can we do to change that behaviour?

---

**Configurations**

There is a total of 35 streams at the moment (This because we have a bunch of applications on our servers).

Every message that is given to Monolog has the same pattern:

```
Acme API Error on "{user action}": {error description}. Additional information: "{more information provided from the API}" on server "{web server name}" and domain "{domain}" for user "{session ID}"
```

The Graylog stream rules are as follows:

```
Host (regex): ^((?!mycompany-staging).)*$    // Needed to show only logs from the live servers
Facility: app
Full Message (regex): Acme API.*
```

(We've also tried to set the `Full Message regex` to `.*Acme API.*` and `Acme API Error.*`, but none of these worked)

The monolog configuration is as follows:

```
// config_prod.yml

// ...
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
            level:        debug
        nested:
            type:         stream
            path:         %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level:        debug
        graylog:
            type:         gelf
            level:        warning
            publisher:
                hostname: mycompany-monitoring.mycompany.ch
// ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be a problem with Graylog2 itself, the stream started working normally after updating Graylog to the newest version and recreating the stream.